# How Can I Speed Up An ADODB Connection

Tags: mysql, excel, ms-access, vba

I am running the code below to retrieve data from my Access Database into Excel. The code takes about 1 minute to execute. There are currently about 500 records with 8 columns. Is there anything I can do to modify my code to run faster?

```vb
Sub sync_Data()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim mysqlSt As String
    Dim rowindex As Long

    mysqlSt = "SELECT pbsclients.client, pbsclients.priority, pbsclients.source, pbsclients.lastcontact, pbsclients.result, pbsclients.nextsteps, pbsclients.attempts, pbsclients.notes FROM pbsclients; "

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    With cn
        .ConnectionString = con1
        .Open
    End With

    rowindex = 2
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open mysqlSt, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    While Not rs.EOF
        Sheet3.Cells(rowindex, 1) = rs!client
        Sheet3.Cells(rowindex, 2) = rs!Priority
        Sheet3.Cells(rowindex, 3) = rs!Source
        Sheet3.Cells(rowindex, 4) = rs!lastcontact
        Sheet3.Cells(rowindex, 5) = rs!result
        Sheet3.Cells(rowindex, 6) = rs!nextsteps
        Sheet3.Cells(rowindex, 7) = rs!attempts
        Sheet3.Cells(rowindex, 8) = rs!Notes

        rowindex = rowindex + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Try [`Range.CopyFromRecordset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset).

Comment: @gserg thanks for your reply, still learning a bit. Where would I place your suggested code?

Comment: Instead of everything between `While Not rs.EOF` and `Wend`.

Comment: Instead of the entire `While...Wend` block, actually. FWIW `While...Wend` is an obsolete construct, should be `Do While...Loop` to allow for `Exit Do` statements.

Comment: @GSerg modified my code to the following `Sheet3.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs` unfortunately this still takes about 45 seconds to execute. Could it be a network issue within my company?

Comment: 500 records in 45 seconds makes no sense, the query is off a single table, no joins, no filters. Does the table have a primary key?

Comment: Why `adOpenDynamic` and `adLockOptimistic`? Are you getting similarly poor performance with the defaults?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon the table does use primary keys, unfortunately i cannot extract the data based of the primary key. I tried your solution, unfortunately the results remain the same.

Comment: You need to hit the index somehow... try `WHERE Id <> 0` (assuming a single-column, autonumber PK)

Comment: Since the performance issue isn't really with the VBA code, consider [edit]ing your post to rather include the table definition

Comment: @MathieuGuindon so far adding `WHERE Id <> 0` made my code execute in 2 seconds. I need to be able to pull the data by using a different filter. Could i re-write my string to meet to conditions on the `WHERE` statement? Ex: `WHERE ID <> 0 & pbsclients.employee = sheet3.range("D5")`

Comment: Try it. Assuming employee is a text field: `WHERE ID <> 0 AND employee ='" & sheet3.range("D5") & "'"`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon got it working! takes 2 seconds to run.

Comment: @June7 thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Here is the working version of my code, takes about 2 seconds to run and retrieve vs 45 seconds - 1 minute with my above code.

```
Sub sync_Data()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim mysqlSt As String
Dim rowindex As Long


mysqlSt = "SELECT pbsclients.client, pbsclients.priority, pbsclients.source, pbsclients.lastcontact, pbsclients.result, pbsclients.nextsteps, pbsclients.attempts, pbsclients.notes FROM pbsclients WHERE Id <> 0 AND pbsclients.branch = '" & Sheet3.Range("Z1") & "'"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With cn
    .ConnectionString = con1
    .Open
    End With
    rowindex = 2
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open mysqlSt, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    Do While Not rs.EOF

    Sheet3.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    Loop

    rs.Close
      cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    Set cn = Nothing
    Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: And you can make your code more clear by removing the `Do While Not rs.EOF` + `Loop` surrounding your `.CopyFromRecordset rs`.